# Xcode acting strange

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcodebuild

I am typing code from Head First iPhone Development (O'reilly) and Xcode will build and run fine once and then, without any modification to the code, the second build will fail. Why?(I'm using command+R)

EDIT:

the first error was something similar to "can not take an object as an argument."

Comment: That seems unlikely; do you have some more details?  What's the error, for example.

Comment: Yes, show us an example of the code that fails and at least what the error message your getting is. It will be a lot easier for us to help that way ;)

Comment: Seems like similar problem to what you asked in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430568/frustrated-with-objective-c-code 3 minutes before this.

Comment: @StefanB - yes, but this is asking specifically about builds failing after a successful build for no apparent reason. I was afraid to lump it together, because I've seen other posters het flamed for it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you must miss some proper argument which should be a pointer type in your method declaration.